# Update Oracle table records timezone values

Tags: sql, timezone, timestamp, oracle11g

I have a table with an Oracle column of TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE. The table contains records of varying timezones. I'd like to update all of the records of the table to be UTC. Is there a recommended way of doing this in an UPDATE query? I've looked at the Oracle methods to_date(), which is for converting a string to a date, and from_tz() which converts a time to a time with timezone.

It seems like I'd need a way to run a query and pull the timezone from the field, and then somehow update the field to put it in UTC. I don't want to simply change the timezone designation, I want to offset the time of day so

```
21-JAN-10 03.28.38.713000000 PM -05:00
```

would become

```
21-JAN-10 08.28.38.713000000 PM UTC
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE "MyDb"."Books"
  (
    "GUID" RAW(32) DEFAULT SYS_GUID(),
     "DATE_CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like

```
UPDATE "Books"
   SET date_created = date_created at time zone 'UTC'
```

which will do something like this

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 timestamp with time zone );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( current_timestamp );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

COL1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-FEB-12 01.38.42.372000 PM -05:00

SQL> update foo
  2     set col1 = col1 at time zone 'UTC';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from foo;

COL1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
13-FEB-12 06.38.42.372000 PM UTC
```

Now, as a style matter, creating case-sensitive table names and column names is highly discouraged as it will greatly annoy the developers that have to maintain the code.

Comment: As I am a developer who uses the table, I agree with you completely. "Books" is just an example here. As always, your Oracle expertise is greatly appreciated. Simple query - works well.

Comment: Is it possible to selectively do an update, only updating dates that are not in UTC? There are triggers that fire when a row is updated, and I'd like to minimize unnecessary row updates.

Comment: I believe I can use to_char(DATE_CREATED, 'TZH') in a WHERE clause.

Comment: UPDATE "Books"
SET date_created = date_created at time zone 'UTC'
WHERE to_char(DATE_CREATED, 'TZH') != '+00';